# VSCode - clangd extension does not format/lint on save

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, static-analysis, clangd

I am using VSCode with the clangd extension for C++ development (through Remote SSH extension). I have my .clang-format and .clang-tidy files with the rules I want to enforce. If I format the code manually (either Ctrl-Alt-F or right click -> Format document) the code gets formatted without any issues. Same if I manually go for the clang-tidy suggested fixes (Ctrl-.). Instead, if I save, nothing happens.

These are my settings overrides for C++. I tried moving them inside the different levels (User, Remote, Workspace) but there is no difference.

```
"[cpp]": {
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true,
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd"
}
```

The same rules for ESLint or rustfmt work with no issues.

Comment: Could you share [clangd logs](https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#gathering-logs) from an editing session where you open a file, introduce a formatting error by typing, and then save the file?

Comment: As for the code action part, this may be a case of missing support in clangd. Could you give a code example with a fix that you can manually accept with `Ctrl-.`?

Comment: Interestingly, at work it does not autoformat, but at home it does, despite having the same configuration. WIll need to dig deeper.

@HighCommander4 an example of code is the following:

`
int x{3};

  if (x == 3) {
    return;
  } else {
    x = 4;
  }`

The rule is `readability-else-after-return`. The else has a squiggly line underneath because the else block should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

I investigated the quick-fix issue a bit, and found that `"editor.codeActionsOnSave": { "source.fixAll": true }` relies on a new Language Server Protocol (LSP) enhancement added in LSP 3.17 (code actions with type `source.fixAll`).

Clangd does not currently support this, but it seems to me like it shouldn't be too difficult to add support for it, as clangd already classifies quick-fixes based on whether they're suitable for being applied automatically (e.g. `Select All --> "Auto Fix..."` makes use of this).

I filed https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/1446 with some more details.